# How to get a list of the nested elements in a collection in Java 8?

Tags: lambda, collections, java-8

I have an object as shown in the image below. I want to generate a list out of it that just has the values stored on 1st index for each of those nested lists. Something like `{domain1.com, domain2.com}` as the output.

I want to do it using Java 8 lambda expressions. I was thinking of using `flatmap` like this `sanList.stream().flatMap(x -> x.get(1).stream())` but it is not compiling.

How should I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `flatMap`, rather a `map` would do the trick. Try this out,

```
List<List<String>> nestedList = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("1", "domain1.com"),
        Arrays.asList("2", "domain2.com"));
List<String> values = nestedList.stream().map(nl -> nl.get(1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(values);
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me. I couldn't figure if I could use map for it.